# Jetpack Joyride issue

Tags: technical-issues, android, jetpack-joyride

So as you can see form the pictures I can not equip my Random Head/Body clothes I do not have such problems with my other clothes whatsoever. Anyone can help? Also I am using Android[image]
[image]